# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function with React Table and moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using React Table module, and I'm trying to make use of `moment` to display a better date format from the `created_at` field of the data passed to `ReactTable` component.

```
let columns = [{
  id: "createdAt",
  Header: "Created",
  accessor: a => <Fragment>{moment(a.created_at).format("MM DD YYYY")}</Fragment>
}];
```

But for some reason, it's whining with the error

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

pointing to this line.

If I simply do `a.created_at` it will display it normally. The module is imported for sure.

Comment: post all your code...are you sure `a.created_at` is not already a moment object?

Comment: Works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/p73pnxjwpj

Comment: @DanielLizik, yes, it is stored as datetime in the database.

Comment: @ChrisG, alone it works, but when specified in the react-table module the error happens. There must be an issue with react-table

Comment: @gamofe I updated the code example with `<ReactTable>`.

Answer (score 27):

I had this error when I am importing moment the wrong way

```
import {moment} from "moment"; // with errors 'Object(...) is not a function'
import moment from "moment"; //no more errors
```

Comment: wow, ran into this answer and saved my day, which kind of wizzary is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

It's may due to wrong import statement

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

don't write

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

or

```
import {moment} from 'moment';
```